# How should I design a SQL table to handle Update and/or Add of multiple rows at once?

Tags: sql-server

I am quite new to handling databases but I've been slowly getting a grasp of it by reading through various tutorials. Now, I've tried it myself in a small project in Java, using H2 for creating a local database and toying around with different small ideas. In one of my small projects I stumbled across a problem I cannot find a good answer for.

I have this table WAREHOUSE

```
| Name  | Stock |
|-------|-------|
| Salt  | 10    |
| Sugar | 5     |
| Wheat | 15    |
| Rice  | 11    |
| Grain | 6     |
```

Then, I get a list of changes, which can contain Increases and Decreases of products. It can also contain New products. This could be an example of a collection of changes:

```
| Name   | Stock |
|--------|-------|
| Salt   | +3    |
| Sugar  | -2    |
| Rice   | -6    |
| Spice  | +10   |
| Rubber | +6    |
```

Now, I have no idea what is the best approach. Should I do a loop through the list and make one query per item in the changes-list? Can I somehow write a query that does the loop? Or can I write a query that can handle that new items gets added to the table in the future?

My current solution looks something like this (pseudo code):

```
for each ( Element in Changes ) {
    ResultSet rs = WarehouseDB.query( Does a row exist with ProductName == Element.ProductName)
    if rs.size() > 0
        WarehouseDB.query( Modify product amount by Element.Change )
    else
        WarehouseDB.query( Add new row (Element.ProductName , Element.Change) ) 
}
```

But there has to be a more effective way. When the warehouse gets big, and the changes list grows, this can result in several 100 queries. Sure, as long as changes doesn't happen frequently that's not a problem per se, but I am interested in what would be a good design here.

The other questions here at SO often have prior knowledge of what elements exists in their tables, but how do I handle future cases where I don't know which products I have in my warehouse? Should I generate a large CASE - query in run time?

Thanks in advance // Gikkman

Comment: You will find various examples if you search for "upsert". For SQL Server, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your list of changes coming from?  If it's coming from an application, you should probably loop through the changes and make separate database calls for each of them.  It's also possible to create an XML object and send that to the database, but that will obfuscate your code and it's only worth it if you're avoiding hundreds of database connections.

However, if the changes are in the database, then this would be really easy to do with an UPDATE FROM statement:

```
UPDATE W
SET W.Stock = W.Stock + S.Stock
FROM WAREHOUSE W
JOIN StockChanges S
    ON W.Name = S.Name
```

**EDIT**

I know you said the changes are coming from an app, but for accuracy, I want to mention that (after you run the update) you need to:

```
DELETE FROM StockChanges
```

to prevent the same changes from being applied multiple times.

Comment: Yes, they come from an application. At the moment, I have a manual interface where I insert the changes and then generate a list from those, but that solution is only for testing purpose. They will in the future be sent via messages to the database application

Comment: If the round trips to the database are lagging your app, you could go the XML route.  It'll be more code, but will result in only one database call - and SQL parses XML very well.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that :-)